# StringBuilder output is empty executing linux echo command

Tags: java, linux, stream, stringbuilder, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute in java this command, and I need to get the output
in a java String. The command encrypt plain text with a password phrase and return the plain text encrypted.

The command is: 
**/bin/sh -c echo "textToEncrypt" | /usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -base64 -A -pass pass:passwordPhrase**

Screenshot:
[image]

I do the following:

1. I can run the command in the linux shell , and I get an encrypted output string in the shell, like: "U2FsdGVkX1/1UcPzhX7IGgvXdx9YrS+cizrla8UYhU8=", so the command works.
2. I can run the same command in java 1.7, like the example code below (cryptData method). It runs fine, but I dont get an output (the encrypted data).
3. I can run any command without "echo" from java, for example, ("ls -fla | more"). Run fine again and I always get the output.

This is the code:

```java
    public void cryptData() {

    String passwordPhrase="a1b2c3d4e5";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();


    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("/bin/sh");
    commands.add("-c");
    commands.add("echo");
    commands.add("/"textToCrypt/"");
    commands.add("|");
    commands.add("/usr/bin/openssl");
    commands.add("-aes-256-cbc");
    commands.add("-e");
    commands.add("-base64");
    commands.add("-A");
    commands.add("-pass");
    commands.add("pass:"+passwordPhrase);



    // Run the shell command
    processBuilder.command(commands);

    try {  //standard stringBuilder process

            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                    System.out.println("Output1"+ output);
                    System.out.println("Output2"+ output.toString());
                    System.exit(0);
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
            }

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

The final result is always: "Success!" but the output is empty or null with this code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be because you're passing "passwordPhrase" as a string and not the value of the variable passwordPhrase?

Comment: I dont think so, because the format is pass:passphrase, and the value or "passwordPhase" it would also work both. I think the problem is not the command itself, is how to get the output for the execution of the command, but I don't know. I  updated the question with an image screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Why does your screenshot show the shell prompt before the supposed output of the command? That doesn't look like the command works, it looks like you pasted the expected output along with the command.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes,you are right.  I used online free shell, I edited the image. I just wanted to show that it worked  [link](https://i.imgur.com/yHoPHCB.png)

Comment: @OscarP It doesn't work though. `sh -c echo "textToEncrypt"` will print an empty line and that will be piped into `openssl`. So it will encode an empty line, not "textToEncrypt".

Comment: @sepp2k I see, so with double quotes, it should work:  sh -c "echo "textToEncrypt"", I think   [link](https://i.imgur.com/DWGgW6h.png)

Comment: @OscarP That doesn't work because of the nested double quotes, but yes, if you remove the inner double quotes, replaced either the inner or outer double quotes with single quotes or escaped the inner double quotes, that would work in the shell. It'd be kinda pointless though because you could just as well write `echo textToEncrypt | ...` and leave out the `sh -c` altogether. In Java you need the `sh -c` to be able to use shell features like piping, but that means you want to pass the whole thing as an argument to `sh -c`, not just `echo textToEncrypt`.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  I´m just migrating php code to java, that is the reason I used that code. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sh -c` expects the command to be executed as a single argument. So after adding `/bin/sh` and `-c`, you should add the rest of the command as a single argument, like this:

```
commands.add("/bin/sh");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add("echo /" + textToCrypt + "/ | /usr/bin/openssl -aes-256-cbc " +
             "-e -base64 -A -pass pass: " + passwordPhrase);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'll check in a few hours.